# Find a linear fractional transformation that maps $(1, 4, ∞)$ onto $(0, 1 - i, 1 + i)$ and another one that maps $|z| = 1$ onto Re$((1 + i)w) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am stuck on these two kind of questions:

1. Find the linear fractional transformation that maps $(1, 4, ∞)$ onto $(0, 1 - i, 1 + i)$.
2. Find the linear fractional transformation that maps the circle $|z| = 1$ onto the line $\operatorname{Re}((1 + i)w) = 0$.

I know how to do type $1$ if there is no infinity in the bracket, but how can I handle the infinity there?

For type $2$, I don't have any idea. I played around with the formula $T(z) = \frac{(az + b)}{(cz + d)}$ but can't get the answer.

Comment: If your linear fractional transform is $(az+b)/(cz+d)$, then $\infty\mapsto a/c$.

Answer (score 0):

If $T(1)=0$, take $T(z)=\dfrac{a(z-1)}{cz+d}$.

If, furthermore, $T(\infty)=1+i$, take $a=1+i, c=1$ and get $T(z)=\dfrac{(1+i)(z-1)}{z+d}$.

Now find $d$ such that $T(4)=1-i$.

Answer (score 0):

For type 2 you can try going from the circle (and form $Re((1+i)w)=0)$ to $(1,0,\infty)$ (choosing any 3 points in the circle and any 3 points in $Re((1+i)w)=0)$). After that use the adecuate composition.

I say to go to $(1,0,\infty)$ because the formulas are well know for that case.

You can find the formulas in the book "Functions of One Complex Variable" of John B. Conway (in the section about Möbius Transformations).

Comment: Type 2: see page 48